# How could I change positions of existing columns in a table with migration?

Tags: yii2, migration

I have a table 'forms' with columns:

```
| id | name | created | enabled
```

How I need to change places between 'created' and 'enabled' columns. How could I do this with migration?

I know that I need to do some like:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY created AFTER enabled
```

but how can I make it via migration?

I already try:

```
$this->alterColumn('fb_forms', 'enabled', 'modify enabled before created');
```

But there are error:

> alter column enabled in table forms to modify enabled before created
>   ...Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'modify enabled before created' at line 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`after()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-columnschemabuilder#after()-detail) method for this:

```
$this->alterColumn('{{%forms}}', 'created', $this->string()->after('enabled'));
```

Comment: oops i never knew about it, **+1**. This makes my answer incorrect in a way that i suggested `execute()` is the only way to do it, deleting now.